# UIscrollview and touchesEnded Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, touches

I have Scrollview under an Imageview. I want `touchesEnded` be called but it is never called so I can not make toolbar(`topToolBar`) disappear when I click the image I put there. How can I make `touchesEnded` work? Below code is in `touchesEnded`. I looked all of the questions asked before but I could not find it. If it is asked before and I missed the question sorry about that.

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];    
if([touch tapCount] == 1)    
{
  if(topToolBar.hidden == NO)    
  {       
    topToolBar.hidden = YES;
  }
  else
  {
    topToolBar.hidden = NO;
  }
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scroll {
  return img;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"];  
  scroll.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
  img.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
  [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Header File:

```
@interface resimlerViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
  IBOutlet UIButton *back;
  IBOutlet UIButton *next;
  IBOutlet UIButton *home;
  IBOutlet UIToolbar *topToolBar;
  IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroll;
  IBOutlet UIImageView *img;
}

@end
```

Comment: This code doesn't help, I want to see the code when you add it in and the view layer as well

Comment: When you post code, make sure it is indented properly so that our eyes don't bleed (I've fixed that for you). Also, inline code should be `surrounded in backticks`, not **in asterisks which makes it bold**. Stack Overflow uses Markdown, which you can learn about here: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax

Comment: Thanks.Sorry about that I did not know. I will stick to it when I post another question.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the image with UIButton if you want to receive touch events for the image. touchesEnded method is for custom UIViews and their controllers. Use a button and subscribe to the events with `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` method.